# open FDA Recalls API endpoint does not have same information as accessdata.fda.gov

Tags: api, openfda

I am trying to pull data from openFDA for a 2007 medical device recall. On the FDA website I can see all the details - https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRES/res.cfm?id=64517 such as Manufacturer Reason for Recall. However, when using openFDA Device Recalls API, it appears that information isn't there. I went to see if the data is in Recalls Enforcement Reports, but that data appears be to only after June 2012. Is there an API to get the Manufacturer Reason for Recall for these older recalls; to match what can be seen on accessdata.fda.gov?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today the openFDA Device Recall API can only provide a subset of data available for a recall; you would have to query [Medical Device Recalls](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRES/res.cfm) separately to get a complete picture. The openFDA team is aware of the issue and is looking for ways to remediate this. We will post back once a solution is in place.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there a way to be notified when openFDA receives such updates; i.e. the addition of data that was not previously available?

Comment: I'd suggest monitoring https://open.fda.gov/about/updates/ for updates and https://github.com/FDA/openfda for new commits.

Comment: Has this been fixed?